# Multi-user timer with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, timer, scheduled-tasks, channel-api

We are implementing multi-user timer with Google App Engine. When the timer ends we need to do some calculations and send results to users. Several users should be able to start and pause the timer from different browsers. We will use Channels API for communication. How could we trigger the calculations at specific time?

One idea that we have is, when the timer starts, to create a push task with `eta` set to timer finish time. When that task runs, check for timer state which is stored in memcache or datastore, and create another task if the state was modified due to pausing the timer. If the timer is finished the task launches the calculations. Are there better approaches, since there is no guarantee that the task will run exactly at `eta`?

Comment: What's the maximum time on your timer, and what kind of precision are you looking for?

Comment: Maximum time on the timer could be around 10 minutes or a little more. Precision of 1-2 seconds would probably be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a constantly repeating task (re-enqueing itself, eventually with a delay specified in seconds) which would check the timer state and perform the calculations if appropriate or just return if not.

Comment: I guess it makes sense not to use `eta` at all and just trigger self-repeating task in a queue with `rate: 1/s` since it's OK for us if there would be delay of a few seconds. For the timer to be more robust, we also plan to implement a call from a JS client that would trigger calculation from an endpoint when time is up.